# Clicking [google+-api] tag results in a tag search for [google] -[api]

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Clicking the tag for [Google+ API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518150/is-there-already-a-google-api) on this page results in a broken search. Instead of returning two results currently listed under [google+-api](/questions/tagged/google%2b-api), it returns the results for [google](/questions/tagged/google) -[api](/questions/tagged/api), or, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google+-api)

This seems to be the fault of the + sign, which is urlencoded, and then decoded as a space.

Comment: It's how [tag:c++-cli] is encoded in the same way, but it doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: Interesting! Good catch.

Comment: It seems the problem is only for tags containing _+-_, as [tag:test-tag-a+-test].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't really support compound tags in the form of

`foo+-bar`

I also don't see the point of an "API" addendum there, since any question about Google+ should be by definition about programming Google+.

So I renamed the tags and merged.